# Is termios supported in msys2? If not, is there a portable way of getting unbuffered I/O?

Tags: c++, curses, termios, unbuffered

The following code works on linux:

```
include <termios.h>

using namespace std;
static struct termios old_terminal_settings;

void setterm() {
  tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &old_terminal_settings);

  // Set terminal to unbuffered input mode
  struct termios new_terminal_settings = old_terminal_settings;
  new_terminal_settings.c_lflag &= ~ICANON;
  tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &new_terminal_settings);
}

void resetterm() {
  // Restore the original terminal settings
  tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &old_terminal_settings);

}

int main() {
  int c;
    setterm();
  while (c = getc(stdin)) {
    putc(c, stdout);
  }
    resetterm();
  return 0;
}
```

When compiled under msys2 with:

```
g++ -g -I/usr/include term.cc
```

it fails to link. I can't find any library with the missing symbols:

```
tcgetattr
tcsetattr
```

I tried:

```
nm /usr/lib/*.a | grep tcgetattr
nm /mingw64/lib/*.s | grep tcsetattr
```

Since there is an include file termios.h I assume there must be a library with the corresponding symbols? If so, how?
If not, is there anything else I can do?

I found a symbol containing the name _nc_term_tcgetattr and tcsetattr  in libncurses.a in /mingw64/lib but it's only part of the curses package. Presumably to use it I would have to use curses.

Comment: You didn't specify which toolchain you are using and MSYS2 provides several.  What is the output of `which g++` and `echo $MSYSTEM` ?

Comment: `tcgetattr` et al is a part of libc on Linux. There are no such functions on Windows. `mingw` is not designed to port Linux/Unix applications to Windows. If you need this, you may have better luck with Cygwin.

Comment: @DavidGrayson /mingw64/bin/g++, MSYSTEM=MINGW64

Comment: Does this answer your question?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/701189/28128

Comment: msys2 uses a fork from cygwin, which sort-of supports termios for its **base** environment.   The regular development tool chain for mingw* don't support this.

Comment: @David Grayson, that was it!

Comment: With msys-2 it links, but it doesn't work -- the code just hangs when it tries to read from the console.